# C++17 if statement with initializer but no condition

Tags: c++, if-statement, c++17

In c++17 you can do the following:

```
if ( init-statement(optional); condition )
```

according to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if

However my compiler (vs2019) allows

```
if ( init-statement )
```

where the init-statement is also the condition. I can't find that this is documented anywhere, is this actually guaranteed to work?

Comment: How `init-statement` is also the condition? What do you mean?

Comment: In the cppreference link you gave, `condition` is permitted to be "declaration of a single non-array variable with a brace-or-equals initializer.", which is what happens here. This is a C++ feature that long predates C++17.

Comment: It would improve the question to give a real example of the code which your compiler allows

Comment: You should really give an example ([MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) of  what you have tried with real code. Otherwise, we are not sure of your interpretation of **init-statement** and thus it makes a poor question)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In C++, a lot of things can go into `condition` that you wouldn't expect to be allowed there. A `condition` for example can be `int i = 20`. `int i = 20` resolves to a value which can be contextually converted into a boolean and tested.

So it's not that your compiler is allowing an `init-statement` without a `condition`. It's that C++ since the beginning has allowed `condition` grammar to include declaring a variable, and your code is simply using that.

Comment: "grammatical *subset*" seems imprecise. E.g. `init-statement` can be `int x,y;` while `condition` can't.

Comment: I wouldn’t expect `int i=20` to be an expression, and it isn’t—perhaps you mean to simply say “that aren’t an expression”?

Comment: So to which value does `int i = 20` not-an-expression resolve? Is it `i` and thus `i!=0`->`false`?

Answer (score 0):

`if` statement does:

- evaluates the output of `condition`
- if `condition`'s return value is `true` (contextually convertible to bool) - it executes
  `{ ... }`
- if `condition`'s return value is `false` - it skips `{ ... }`

So in your case, the `if` simply executes `init-statement` , and it's return value is not `false` so it executes the rest of your code (`{ ... }`).