# Init-Statment Conditional Expression C++

Tags: c++, initialization, conditional-statements

Can someone please explain to me initializations in if-statements?

This question here is almost the same as mine [C++17 if statement with initializer but no condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59205137/c17-if-statement-with-initializer-but-no-condition) but I don't feel the responses there were adequate.

Why does this work?

```
if( int x = 4 ){ 
  std::cout << x;
}
```

I was under the impression that initialization does not return a value. Indeed the code below is an error:

```
std::cout << ( int y = 7 );
```

Quoting from the Standard N4380, the syntax should be:

"if constexpr_opt ( init-statement_opt condition ) statement"

And quoting further along:

"An if statement of the form
if constexpr_opt ( init-statement condition ) statement
is equivalent to

{
init-statement
if constexpr_opt ( condition ) statement
}"

And also:

"[Note: An init-statement ends with a semicolon.
—end note]"

I can imagine the "int x=4" is the init-statement. But

- then the condition statement, in the example I gave, is missing and the condition statement is **not** marked as optional
- and the init-statement **does not end in a semicolon**.

**EDITED**: removed an incorrect statement.

Comment: What do you mean? It [works](https://godbolt.org/z/_Bv738)

Comment: Are you using a modern C++ compiler that supports the latest C++ standard, which implements this new syntax?

Comment: @cigien: I did not say it works. I said "the above does not work". But from reading the Standard, it seems like what I wrote at the end should be the correct syntax. I'd appreciate some help in understanding what is meant in the 3 passages I quoted.

EDIT: It does work on a C++17 compiler. I take that back. Try it on https://wandbox.org/

Comment: @SamVarshavchik ah, I see that syntax does work. I wasn't using a C++17 compiler. The rest of my question stands, though. Why does an initialization statement seem to return a value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not new C++17 syntax. It has always been there.

`int x = 4` in your first example is *not* the *init-statement*, but the *condition* in the grammar rule you quoted.

*condition* can be either an expression or a declaration with initializer (and a few other restrictions). If it has the latter form, then the declaration introduces the declared variable in the branches of the `if` and the first branch is chosen if the declared variable, contextually converted to `bool`, yields `true` after its initialization.

Comment: Thank you! This clarified things a lot. I was completely misunderstanding what was written! Is there a passage in the Standard you could refer to about the form a condition must take, if you know off-hand?

Comment: @user137364 https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/stmt.stmt#nt:condition