# What if declared variable in condition of if statement is not convertible to bool

Tags: c++

The [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) says in the syntax of `if` statement that:

> *attr*(optional) if constexpr(optional) ( *init-statement*(optional) *condition* ) *statement-true*
> ...
> *condition*   -   one of
>
> - expression which is contextually convertible to `bool`
> - declaration of a single non-array variable with a brace-or-equals initializer.

But for the second choice, the variable is not requested to be contextually convertible to `bool`

So I tried

```cpp
struct Foo { int val; };
int foo() {
    if (Foo x{}) { return 1; }
    return 0;
}
```

and I got an error with both gcc and clang.

Clang said that `error: value of type 'Foo' is not contextually convertible to 'bool'` and gcc gave a similar message `error: could not convert 'x' from 'Foo' to 'bool'`.

So my question is, is it just omitted as a consensus, or I missed something? Thanks ;)

---

**Update:**
Thanks for @Sneftel! I've found in https://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.pre#5:

> The value of a *condition* that is an initialized declaration in a statement other than a `switch` statement is the value of the declared variable contextually converted to `bool`.

Comment: What would you expect the effect of that code to be, if it compiled?

Comment: @JasonLiam I don’t see any lack of research effort here.

Comment: @JasonLiam Sorry, but I've searched for that on both google and stackoverflow and got nothing answering my question... In fact I'm just wondering if the reference forgot the restriction that the variable has to be convertible to `bool`

Comment: @XuanInsr You need to define a conversion to bool. See [working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/78W7TK5K9) and also dupe: [Init-Statment Conditional Expression C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61219162/init-statment-conditional-expression-c)

Comment: @Sneftel Hmm... actually nothing? I don't expected it to compile as the variable is not expected to be convertible to `bool`, but I just go through the reference and found there seems to be not rigorous enough? But actually I'm not very sure about that so I asked here :)

Comment: @JasonLiam as OP quoted, the reference says "one of", hence the confusion. In both cases, the condition needs to be convertible to bool, but it is only mentioned in only one of the cases

Comment: cppreference isn’t the official standard, it’s a community-maintained abstract of the standard. The actual standard is clearer about the need for the conversion to succeed. See https://www.eel.is/c++draft/#stmt.stmt

Comment: The standard only requires, in this context, that `Foo` can be converted to a `bool`.  (From memory - I'd have to look it up - that can be achieved if `Foo` is convertible to a numeric type (e.g. it has an `operator int()`) or to a pointer - since both numeric types and pointers can be converted to `bool`).

Comment: @Sneftel Thanks! I've found in eel.is/c++draft/stmt.pre#5: The value of a condition that is an initialized declaration in a statement other than a switch statement is the value of the declared variable contextually converted to bool.

Comment: @JasonLiam: This question is not about how to use init statements in a condition, it's not a duplicate!

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt It is a dupe because the target [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61219162/init-statment-conditional-expression-c) mentions that there is contextual conversion to bool in the second case as well which implies that cppreference should add the contextual conversion to bool in the second case as well.

Comment: Add this method to **Foo**:  `explicit operator bool() const { return true; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So my question is, is it just omitted as a consensus, or I missed something?

From [stmt.pre#4](https://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.pre#5):

> The value of a *condition* that is an initialized declaration in a statement other than a `switch` statement is the value of the declared variable **contextually converted to `bool`**.

(emphasis mine)

This means that in the second case, the value of the declared variable must be contextually converted to bool which is not the case in your example and hence the error.

This in turn means that the quoted statement from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) in your question should add this "contextual conversion to bool" in their 2nd case.